# JQuery clearInterval & scope

Tags: jquery, variables, scope, setinterval

If I have 2 jQuery scripts/plugins (a + b) ,a instigates b and b has an interval (setInterval). How can I clearInterval b from a?

I've tried global variables & passing an intervalID to b from a but as yet to no avail

I want it to cancel before it can count to 3:

```
// Plugin a
; (function($) {
    var xIntervalID;
    jQuery.fn.CallA = function() {
        $().IamB(xIntervalID, 4000);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $().CancelA(xIntervalID);
        }, 11000);
    }
    jQuery.fn.CancelA = function(IntervalID) {
        clearInterval(IntervalID);
        alert('Cancel called!');
    }

})(jQuery);

// Plugin b
; (function($) {
    jQuery.fn.IamB = function(xIntervalID,Interval) {
        var Something = 0;
        xIntervalID = setInterval(function() {
            Something += 1;
            alert(Something);
        }, Interval);
    }

})(jQuery);



// Start
$().CallA();
```

Comment: Please show your code. You have to pass the ID from b to a.

Comment: I think you should use `setTimeout()` as they are alot more easier to control, and you can always keep it on a endless loop as I personally find intervals alot more difficult to deal with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two possibilities if you want to stick with `setInterval`. Either return the ID from plugin B:

```
jQuery.fn.CallA = function() {
    var xIntervalID = $().IamB(xIntervalID, 4000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $().CancelA(xIntervalID);
    }, 11000);
}

jQuery.fn.IamB = function(Interval) {
    var Something = 0;
    return setInterval(function() {
        Something += 1;
        alert(Something);
    }, Interval);
}
```

or pass an *object* to plugin B. Objects are passed by reference:

```
jQuery.fn.CallA = function() {
    var xIntervalID = {};
    $().IamB(ID, 4000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $().CancelA(xIntervalID.id);
    }, 11000);
}

// in B:

jQuery.fn.IamB = function(xIntervalID,Interval) {
    var Something = 0;
    xIntervalID.id = setInterval(function() {
        Something += 1;
        alert(Something);
    }, Interval);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Felix, I actually just resolved it using a callback function to pass the IntervalID back to a after it had been set in b (exactly what part1 of your answer denotes). I prefer your solution though because it's more streamlined. Superb, thank you so much